# Geo Fencing in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to build geo fencing in my android application. however i am not clear with this idea. whenever user opens my app, i want to see if he is in any AMC theater. how do i do that? should i use latitude longitude values or i should use physical address? if i use lat lon values how accurate will the output be? if i go for physical address, how time efficient will it be?
i have currently written a code wherein i have hardcoded the values. but thats not going to work for real app. my app can track users coordinates but i am not clear how this data can b put to use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use latitude and longitude, with very less accuracy (may be 20meters or less), and just look for Satellite GPS coordinates. If the device gets a satellite GPS fix, it would have very good accuracy (sometimes as close as 5m), and based on that, do whatever task you want to perform.

Comment: hi nithin, thanks for your reply. I used Google Places Api for this (my app is not ready yet) the problem with this is, even if i am 2 blocks away from AMC, the app still shows i am in AMC, or to put it simply even if i am 2 blocks away from AMC i can still checkin. so this is not accurate enough.. do u have any other idea? can wifi be used??

Comment: Using wifi would be a bad idea from my point of view..I mean, the accuracy is bad. But if you can get the list of access points of the places where your users may check in, then you are good. You can just see what access point he is connected to, and if its in ur list, you can mark it as checked in. (But having the list of all those access points is a pain though)

Comment: hi Nithin, thanks for getting back to me.. i totally get your point.. wifi is not a good option as i wont be having list of access points.. so what can be a better solution? i am out of ideas.. all i can think of now is a donkey method where i will have to manually enter all  d addresses; i will extraxt users location, send it server;server will process it by matching the received coordinates with all the coordinates in db (tables will be created based on coordinates) and the send us back the result.. but i am not sure what will be the performance of this method.. can u suggest a better idea?

Comment: Right, I don't think your method will work too. The reason being, when you extract user's location, it can again be a bit inaccurate, like about 100m accuracy. Can't think of a better solution, but if I were you, I would check if the GPS accuracy is less than 10 to 20m, and if it is within the location's latitude longitude, with a radius of about 30m, then you checkin..got it?

Comment: yes, i got it.. for now i think i will go with google places api for i think what i am expecting is far too precise and it is very difficult to implement.. if i come across something good, i will have it posted here.. thanks for your help Nithin!

Answer (score 0):

Best bet is to get the lat/lon coordinates of nearby AMC Theaters from the Google Places API.  Calculate the distance to any of the points and use a threshold to determine if you're in the general vicinity of the building.  The geolocation point is bound to be on the edge of the building, not the center of it (or perhaps even on the street), so it's unlikely you can just use a simple radius from the point.

For geo fencing, the best bet is to scan for the WiFi networks in the area and if any match the properties of your desired location, then you're in it.  Of course, good luck getting that data.  The other thing you could do to ensure users are in the venue is to plant NFC tags in the building and have them scan the tags.  Again, this may only be feasible if you're doing a contract for AMC.  QR codes are too easy to duplicate.  Anyone could take a picture of one and scan it at any time.

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for you kind guidance. Google places API seems quite promising. however the way my app will work is, the user has to be in AMC to to see the features that i am going to provide in my app.. so if the user is in AMC and my app does not recognize that, he will get different set of features. so my point over here is, the user will be somewhere in the AMC and my app should be able to determine that.. any suggestion on this?